# Position div to the corner of the button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

As shown in above image, I need to position DIV on the corner of the button clicked. This button can be any where on the page but when clicked it is opening a div and I want to set the position so it opens the div on its corner like in the image.

The div I want to open will be outside of div containing the button.

```js
function openPopup() {
  document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'contents';
}

function closePopup() {
  document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
.popup-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
}

.popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  border: 2px solid grey;
  z-index: 100000000000000000;
  display: none
}

.cancel {
  display: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  height: 10px;
  width: 14px;
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 100000000000000000;
}

.cancel:hover {
  background: rgb(255, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class=" popup-div">
  This is a test message
  <div class="cancel" onclick="closePopup();"></div>
</div>

<button onClick="openPopup();">BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: Fiddle for the same, till what I have completed : https://jsfiddle.net/uhj4o269/

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <button>Button</button>
    <div id="popup"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.cont {
    position: relative;
}

#popup {
    position: absolute;
    top: /* insert button height (incl. padding) here */
}
```

Comment: The div I want to open will be outside of button div.

Comment: Button and Div wont be in same divs

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  height: 85%;
  width: 40%;
  background: red;
  font-size: 55px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {}

.clsbtn {
  margin-left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<div class="container">

  <br> <br> <br>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('popup').style.display='block'">Button</button>
  <div id="popup">
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none'" class="clsbtn">&times;</span>
    <h1> div </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```